# ref array inside $refs undefine inside mounted()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm working on a simple image slider component. In the template I'm using `v-for` to create the `img` tags and `ref` to keep a reference to each one of them.

```
Vue.component('slide', {
    template: `
    <div class="c-image-slider">
      <img ref="im" :key="image" class="c-image-slider__slide" v-for="image in images" :src="image">
    </div>
    `,
    data() {
      return {
        currentImage: 0,
        images: [],
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      this.images = images;
      console.log(this.$refs);
      console.log(this.$refs.im);
    },
  });
```

Inside the `mounted()` hook of the component I'm trying to log the `this.$refs.im` array, but I get `undefined` as a result, even though, the array is definetely there. What am I missing?

Here is also a pen replicating the issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LQMMBK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Re-renders are *asychronous*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue). When you set the images in mounted here:

```
this.images = images;
```

You trigger a re-render, but Vue does not immediately do it. *Prior* to that, there are no `$refs` because **no images are rendered yet**.

When you immediately log `$refs`, its logging exactly what it is *at that point in time*. Then the scheduled re-render occurs, and Vue populates `$refs`.

You can use [$nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) to log it out properly.

```
mounted() {
  this.images = images;
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    console.log(this.$refs);
    console.log(this.$refs.im);
  })
}
```

Updated [pen](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/EQGrBK?editors=1010).

Comment: I had no idea about that. Though, looking at my original pen, why in the first `console.log` the array appeared to be set?
And is $nextTick the only way to do it or would it be a better approach?

Comment: @carlo `console.log` is a little misleading sometimes in that if you log an object, and that object is later updated, then log will show the updated object when you inspect it. For example, open your pen, and then open the log. Then click Run for the pen again. Notice that what is logged is an empty object `{}`, but if you *inspect* it, it shows the `im` property, because that is the current state of the object. Basically I expect console.log outputs a reference to the object, and when you inspect it shows the current state.

Comment: @Carlo from official documentation: An important note about the ref registration timing: because the refs themselves are created as a result of the render function, you cannot access them on the initial render - they don’t exist yet! $refs is also non-reactive, therefore you should not attempt to use it in templates for data-binding.

Comment: @DobleL what shall I use instead, then?

Comment: @DobleL @carlo That's misleading. `mounted` is *after* the initial render. It's the event that signals the first render is complete. Using `$refs` in mounted is perfectly legit. If, for example, images was assigned in `data`, then both objects would be logged correctly. Here is an example. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/wyROZv

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
updated() {
  this.images = images;
  console.log(this.$refs);
  console.log(this.$refs.im);
}
```